# persistent view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Im building an iphone radio application and I want to have the controls, play, pause, stop, etc. in a tool bar (a custom view controller) at the bottom of the application. I want to keep this there throughout all the views so you can control the audio while navigating through the other parts of the application (multiple view/table controllers).

Is there a way to create a view that stays in place like a tab bar?

Answer (score 0):

The idea here would be to check the view position with respect to ur window (UIWindow present in the application delegate). Lets say u call this view PL now each time any view is pushed on the window, you have to check the position of this view PL if this view is not the last view in the stack make it the last view, This can also be done by checking in viewWillDisappear.

Hope this give u an idead of what to do.

Thanks,

Madhup